# Why is atom io editor too slow?

Tags: text-editor

I am new to Atom io editor. I have two issues with it:

1. It takes too long to load compared to Notepad++
2. It has all these Welcome tabs opening at the start every time.

Can someone help me to resolve these issues?

Comment: The latest release for the Atom editor is also slow. But their features are very tempting to you. I have started using Visual Code Editor. They pretty much have similar packages from Atom and it is relatively faster.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to disable the Welcome screen under Settings -> Packages -> Welcome.  Under settings you can uncheck Show on Startup.

There's also a checkbox on the Welcome Screen to "Show Welcome Guide when opening Atom."  I haven't tried it myself, but that might fix part of your issue.